# There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

When I run the command "vagrant up", I am getting the following error, Can any one tell me what was the issue and how to resolve it ?

```
E:\World_Bank\Vagrant_05Aug2014>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'test-phil'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: Vagrant_05Aug2014_default_1407255316443_73721
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["showvminfo", "69def451-086c-436f-8d8d-0439cb3b7107", "--machinereadable"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine with UUID {69def451-086c-436f-8d8
d-0439cb3b7107}
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, int
erface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(VMNameOrUuid).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at lin
e 2611 of file VBoxManageInfo.cpp

E:\World_Bank\Vagrant_05Aug2014>VBoxManage showvminfo 69def451-086c-436f-8d8d-0439cb3b7107 --machine
readable
'VBoxManage' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar problem for anyone who comes across this, and it was likely because VirtualBox was not in my path.  Add this `C:\PROGRA~2\Oracle\VirtualBox` to your path environment variable.

Comment: The above issue is due of invalid synch path in vagrant file. Please make sure that your synch folder is correct