# There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

When running vagrant up I get the following error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Importing base box 'lavash-devstack'...
    Progress: 10%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
    for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

    Command: ["import", "C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/home/boxes/lavash-devstack/0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "devstack_default_1416365851757
    _3107_1428337748513_82036", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "10", "--disk", "C:\\Users\\adrian espinoza\\VirtualBox VMs\\devstack_default_1416365851757_3107_
    1428337748513_82036\\box-disk1.vmdk"]

    Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
    Interpreting C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\home\boxes\lavash-devstack\0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
    OK.
    0%...10%...
    Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\adrian espinoza\VirtualBox VMs\devstack_default_1416365851757_3107_1428337748513
    _82036\box-disk1.vmdk'.
    VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in 'C:\Users\adrian espinoza\VirtualBox VMs\devstack_default_1416365851757_3107_1428337
    748513_82036/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Does someone know what is wrong? I reviewed the related questions, and applied the possibles solution but I still get the error. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143826/there-was-an-error-while-executing-vboxmanage-a-cli-used-by-vagrant)

Comment: Looks like you have a "disk full" error trying to write under C:\Users. It might be actually out of space, or might not be writeable.

Answer (score 4):

You problem is similar to me. It may because you did not get enough permission. I run vagrant in git on Windows 8.1. I solve this problem by restart git in administration mode. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling upon this while pasting their error directly, it appears to be a VirtualBox problem, not a vagrant problem.

I'm running macOS Sierra, and started running into this issue after my upgrade. I downloaded VirtualBox again, and re-installed which began the upgrade process.

After that was complete, my vagrant environments were set.